# Python-PPTX : How to access autoshapes on a slide?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have a slide_layout with a rectangle created manually in Powerpoint (Insert > Shapes > Rectangle). Since it is a rectangle, it must be an auto-shape.

When I try to list the shapes on a slide made from that slide_layout, I don't find the rectangle-shape listed. I'm using the following script to list the shapes:

```
prs = Presentation('./Template.pptx')
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[idx])

for shape in slide.shapes:
    print(str(shape.shape_id) + " : " + str(shape.shape_type))
```

I want to be able to access the manually added auto-shapes to delete them when not needed. They are currently just UI elements on my slide_layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-placeholder items on a layout *appear* (visually) on a slide created from that layout, but no such shapes are actually present on the slide. You can see this in PowerPoint by trying to select the rectangle on a slide created by the layout. Such a "shape" cannot be either selected or deleted.

There is an option to "show background graphics" (Format > Slide Background > Hide Background Graphics), which, if turned off, will hide these things; but it's all or nothing. You can't select which background shapes will be visible.

You might consider creating two layouts, one with the rectangle and one without, and selecting the appropriate layout at slide creation time. Otherwise, you'll need to place the rectangle on each slide as its own shape.

Comment: Yea I had tried selecting the shape but it wasn't getting selected like you pointed out. Thanks for clarifying this about non-placeholder items. I finally decided to create a shape object at slide creation time, only at places I needed it.